# How to read multiple .dat files of data cubes using the multibandread command?

Tags: matlab

I have several files that need to be read by the `multibandread` function in Matlab.

I have done them one by one but it takes a very long time. The files have the same `.dat` extension. Here is how I read the `.dat` files individually :

```
X = multibandread('filename.dat', [x,y,z], 'uint8', 0, 'bil', 'ieee-le');
```

Comment: If you can share your code, it would be easier to understand the context and the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop over a cell containing your filenames:

```matlab
filenameCell = {'file1.dat', … , 'file2.dat'};
for i = 1:size(filenameList,2)
    multibandread(filenameCell{i},...) % filenameCell{i} takes the i-th filename in the cell
    ...
end
```